# How to apply multiple sort criteria on views?

Tags: 8, views

I have created a view where I used

> Display a specified number of items | 5 items

And I have 2 sort criterias.

> SORT CRITERIA
>
> Add sort criteria
>
> List additional actions Content:
>
> Authored on (desc)
>
> Content: Page Views (desc)

What I want is sort criteria 1 should be applicable on first 3 rendered items, and sort criteria 2 should be applied on next 2 items. So here right now, total 5 items are displaying. From them, I want first 3 items to pass from sort criteria 1 and other 2 items from sort criteria 2.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: `What I want is filter 1` ... `and filter 2` I don't see any filters... I only see **sorts**. Sorting is not the same as filtering.

Comment: My apologies.. Its all about sort criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions can be using 2 views and use one view as footer attachment to the other view

View 1 with sort criteria 1 (no of items 3)
View 2 with sort criteria 2 (no of items 3)

For View 1 footer, use View 2

Comment: Not so fast, what if the #1 in page views also happen to be one of the last 3 authored? You end up with an item being listed twice (duplicate)